# Extract child attribute

Tags: jquery, html

```
    <div id="OverallContainer">
            <div class="sort con drop" id="LayoutContainer1">
                <div title="LayoutContainer" class="drag" id="Layout">
                    <div class="container con" id="Layoutpanel">
                        <div class="header" data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" title="Drag Me">
                            <div class="ctrls">
                                <div class="btn-group  pull-right">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down dropdown-toggle Conficons" data-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" title="Menu"></span>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#" onclick="AddNewClick(this.title)" data-toggle="modal" title="Layoutframe">Change</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" onclick="RemoveClick(this.title)" title="LayoutContainer">Remove</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="LayoutRegion" class="dragbox-content">
                            <iframe id="Layoutframe" class="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sort con drop" id="LayoutContainer2">
                <div title="LayoutContainer" class="drag" id="Layout">
                    <div class="container con" id="Layoutpanel">
                        <div class="header" data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" title="Drag Me">
                            <div class="ctrls">
                                <div class="btn-group  pull-right">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down dropdown-toggle Conficons" data-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" title="Menu"></span>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#" onclick="AddNewClick(this.title)" data-toggle="modal" title="Layoutframe">Change</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" onclick="RemoveClick(this.title)" title="LayoutContainer">Remove</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="LayoutRegion" class="dragbox-content">
                            <iframe id="Layoutframe" class="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="sort con drop" id="LayoutContainer3">
                <div title="LayoutContainer" class="drag" id="Layout">
                    <div class="container con" id="Layoutpanel">
                        <div class="header" data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" title="Drag Me">
                            <div class="ctrls">
                                <div class="btn-group  pull-right">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down dropdown-toggle Conficons" data-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" title="Menu"></span>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#" onclick="AddNewClick(this.title)" data-toggle="modal" title="Layoutframe">Change</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" onclick="RemoveClick(this.title)" title="LayoutContainer">Remove</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="LayoutRegion" class="dragbox-content">
                            <iframe id="Layoutframe" class="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
Like wise many LayoutContainers
        </div>
```

I m dynamically generating "Layoutcontainer" inside "Overall container" 
Each and every LayoutContainers consist of Iframe tag like above code, 
i need to extract a "src" of iframe of all the child container using jquery

i tried this but its repeating the url

```
 $('#OverallContainer > div').each(function () {
        saveUrl1 += $('#OverallContainer').find('.frame').attr('src');
        saveUrl1 += ",";
    });
```

and

```
 $('#OverallContainer > div').each(function () {
        saveUrl1 += $('#OverallContainer .frame[src]').prop('src');
        saveUrl1 += ",";
    });
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56877/discussion-between-anoop-joshi-and-amit-kumar).

Comment: @JackAdam : no actually he is right. you didn't clear your question and also didn't show what you have tried. that's why your question has been put on hold.
if you will modify your question then they will vote up for open your question.

Comment: @Amit Kumar : Ok amit thank you, I have another question also, but my account was blocked now and i cant able to ask question now. :(

Comment: yes. i think , now you are seeing "we are no longer accepting question from this account" . something like this. 
so better to create a new account , and read ask your questions very clearly from the next time. and also show your code, whatever you have tried.

Comment: Can i edit this question ?

Comment: yes . edit your question. 
as i don't have right to vote up for open your question. hope they will open it again. but still you won't be able to ask question.

Comment: I edited the question, and I also included my tried code, Pls view that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#OverallContainer` have 2 divs, you iterate over them but then you search for all iframes globably, so even that your iframe is one, you ask for it two times.

so you need to use `$(this).find('iframe');` so it's iframe but relative to the div you iterate on.

here is the code:

```
var urls=[];
$('#OverallContainer > div').each(function () {
    var iframe = $(this).find('iframe');
    if (iframe.length) { // item exists
        urls.push(iframe.attr('src'));
    }
});
saveUrl1 = urls.join(',');
```

or shorter:

```
saveUrl1 = $('#OverallContainer > div iframe').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).get().join(',');
```

Comment: Please View my edited code, May be this will be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution:

```
$('#OverallContainer > div').each(function () {
            saveUrl1 += $(this).find("iframe").prop("src");
            saveUrl1 += ",";
        });
```